Any way to ignore check digit errors
I am trying to read EAN-13 barcodes that were generated sequentially. Unfortunately the barcodes were submitted manually by the user, meaning the last digit of 13-digit EAN is not the checkdigit, but the sequence, such as 8690000236040, 8690000236041, 8690000236042 etc.
Is there anyway I can bypass the check digit validation, and read the barcode?
I have tried to modify the js code but, obviously failed.
Thanks
